# FFmpeg HLS save original timestamps

Tags: ffmpeg, timestamp, http-live-streaming, transcoding, video-conversion

I transcoding a video to HLS and everything works fine with the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i source -vcodec nvenc -acodec copy -f ssegment -segment_list playlist.m3u8 -segment_list_flags +live -segment_time 60 -segment_list_size 10 out%03d.ts
```

But when I want to save an original timestamps and add **-copyts** key to my commnad then I received new .ts file each 0.7 seconds(but I set it to 60 seconds *-segment_time 60*). 
**How can I save an original timestamps with transcoding to HLS ?** 
**UPDATE:** I tried this command and timestamps are saves fine:

```
ffmpeg -i source.ts -vcodec nvenc -acodec copy -f hls -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 5 -copyts playlist.m3u8
```

But when I trying run this command for RTP input stream then I receive the following error: *"Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:2 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height"*.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this:

> ffmpeg -y -i source -c copy -copyts -f mpegts - 1> 'ffmpeg -y -vcodec
>   nvenc -acodec copy -f hls -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 5 -copyts
>   playlist.m3u8'

Comment: Thanks! It isn't a best way, but it helped!